# Count value and group by type and date

Tags: mysql

i have this table 
(date format : dd/mm/yyyy)

```
+ order_id + buyer +    date    +    status   +
+----------+-------+------------+-------------+
+  CSR001  +  AAA  + 01/01/2020 +  delivered  +
+  CSR002  +  AAA  + 03/01/2020 +   canceled  +
+  CSR003  +  BBB  + 01/01/2020 +  delivered  +
+  CSR004  +  BBB  + 04/01/2020 +  delivered  +
+  CSR005  +  AAA  + 01/02/2020 +   canceled  +
+  CSR006  +  BBB  + 01/02/2020 +  delivered  +   
+  CSR007  +  AAA  + 01/02/2020 +  delivered  +
+  CSR008  +  AAA  + 01/02/2020 +  delivered  +
+----------+-------+------------+-------------+
```

what is the query to create view in mysql and make it like this, (Group By buyer, status, and count how many of delivered/cancelled value every month)

```
 + buyer   +  status   +  january  +  february  +
+----------+-----------+-----------+------------+
+  AAA     + delivered +     1     +      2     +
+  AAA     + cancelled +     1     +      1     +
+  BBB     + delivered +     2     +      0     +
+  BBB     + cancelled +     0     +      0     +
+----------+-----------+-----------+------------+
```

Comment: look up pivot tables.

Comment: `date format : dd/mm/yyyy)` so fix that. The efficiency of relational databases comes with the correct use of data types.

Comment: And then, for the next part, consider handling issues of data display in application code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have condition inside `count` to differentiate the month:

```
SELECT t.buyer,
       t.status,
       COUNT(IF(MONTH(t.date) = 1, 1, NULL)) AS jan,
       COUNT(IF(MONTH(t.date) = 2, 1, NULL)) AS feb
FROM TABLE AS t
GROUP BY buyer,
         status;
```

Comment: and how if i add more data in the future, example until 2021, and make sure this query wont count both january from 2020 and 2021?

Comment: You can simply add more conditions the `IF` function

Comment: can you give me an example where should i put YEAR alogside MONTH on IF function? already search on stackoverflow but cant find right keyword